# Very accurate approximations for $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{a^n-1}$ and $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^{2m+1}}{e^n-1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, approximation, bernoulli-numbers

Apologies if this has been asked before, since it seems rather simple. I enjoy messing around with formal mathematics, and I once derived the following formula which holds for many functions (see my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1988553/criteria-for-formally-derived-euler-maclaurin-type-formula); no-one has yet responded to my request for criteria describing for which $q(x)$ it holds):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}q(n)=\int_{0}^{\infty}q(s)ds-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{B_{k}q^{[k-1]}(0)}{k!}\tag{*}$$

where $B_n$ are the [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number). Using this formula with $q(x)=\frac{x}{e^x-1}$ and the identities $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}=\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)$ and $\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{B_n}{n!}x^n$, it was easy to show (since $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{n}{e^n-1}}=0$) that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{e^n-1}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{B_n B_{n+1}}{n!(n+1)!}$$

But the odd Bernoulli numbers are zero past $n=3$ so that we get:

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{e^n-1}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{11}{24}\tag{1}$$

Now this is very accurate indeed; [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sum%20n%3D1%20to%20infinity%20n%2F((e%5En)-1))-(((pi%5E2)%2F(6))-((11)%2F(24)))) declares the error to be on the order of $10^{-16}$. Further, using $(*)$ for $q(x)=\frac{x^{2m+1}}{e^x-1}$ in a similar manner gives:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{2m+1}}{e^n-1}=\Gamma(2m+2)\zeta(2m+2)-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{B_n B_{2m+n+1}}{n!(2m+n+1)!}$$

which simplifies to:

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{2m+1}}{e^n-1}=(2m+1)!\zeta(2m+2)+\frac{B_{2m+2}}{2(2m+2)!}\tag{2}$$

For $m=1$ this gives:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^3}{e^n-1}=\frac{\pi^4}{15}-\frac{1}{1440}$$

which [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sum%20n%3D1%20to%20infinity%20(n%5E3)%2F((e%5En)-1))-(((pi%5E4)%2F(15))-((1)%2F(1440)))) declares to have an error on the order of $10^{-3}$. The $m=2$ case [appears](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sum%20n%3D1%20to%20infinity%20(n%5E5)%2F((e%5En)-1))-(((pi%5E6%20*5!)%2F(945))%2B((1)%2F(60480)))) to also have an error on the order of $10^{-3}$.

If we use $q(x)=\frac{bx}{e^{bx}-1}$ in $(*)$ and then set $b=\ln{a}$ then I think we get the following purported identity:

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{a^n-1}=\frac{\pi^2}{6(\ln{a})^2}-\frac{1}{2\ln{a}}+\frac{1}{24}\tag{3}$$

The accuracy of $(3)$ appears extremely good; e.g. for $a=2$ it is [$10^{-16}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sum%20n%3D1%20to%20infinity%20n%2F((2%5En)-1))-(((pi%5E2)%2F(6*((ln(2))%5E2)))-(1%2F(2*ln(2)))%2B(1%2F24))), for $a=3$ it is [$10^{-15}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sum%20n%3D1%20to%20infinity%20n%2F((3%5En)-1))-(((pi%5E2)%2F(6*((ln(3))%5E2)))-(1%2F(2*ln(3)))%2B(1%2F24))), and for $a=6$ it is [still $10^{-9}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sum%20n%3D1%20to%20infinity%20n%2F((6%5En)-1))-(((pi%5E2)%2F(6*((ln(6))%5E2)))-(1%2F(2*ln(6)))%2B(1%2F24))). All of this makes me believe that these formula are not exactly correct, but their accuracy amazes me. I don't know if what's going on in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1943244/on-the-general-form-of-the-family-sum-n-1-infty-fracnke2n-pi-1?rq=1) has any relevance here.

My questions are: Can anyone confirm that all of the highlighted expressions are in fact only approximations, or are some of them actually correct? What in general are the error terms for $(2)$ and $(3)$? Can anyone explain why these expressions are in fact so accurate?

Comment: The linked question in your post is fully relevant here.

Comment: These series have closed forms in terms of [q-Polygamma functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html). For example, we can easily show that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{e^n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{e^k}{(e^k-1)^2}=\psi_e^{(1)}(1)-1$$ The more general sums in your title can be similarly deduced in terms of these functions

Comment: @YuriyS So does that mean that $(1)$ is not correct, but just a very good approximation?

Comment: @Anon, yes, there really is error of about $2.8 \times 10^{-16}$. Even your title says 'approximations' so what did you expect? The exact value up to $30$ digits is: $$1.18660073351489282058550012820$$ While your approximation gives: $$1.18660073351489310313908183331$$

Comment: @YuriyS Thank you for your reply. I was expecting approximations, but just thought I'd clarify. Do you know why $\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{11}{24}$ should be such a good approximation?

Comment: (*) is Euler-McLauren summation formula.

Comment: @Nemo I know it's similar, but without the remainder term. I'm not sure what the remainder term should be in this case though.

Comment: Strangely enough I just posted a very similar question to this!  I too was experimenting with these sorts of sums and arrived similar approximations via umbral methods.  If you are interested my question can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2872627/approximations-to-series-of-ramanujan-type

Answer (score 3):

Let $q = e^{-1}$ then $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{e^{n} - 1} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{nq^{n}}{1 - q^{n}} = \frac{1 - P(q)}{24}$$ where $P(q)$ is a famous Ramanujan's function. It is known from the theory of elliptic and theta functions that if $q = \exp(-\pi K'/K)$ then $$P(q) = \left(\frac{2K}{\pi}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{6E}{K} + k^{2} - 5\right)$$ Note that in your case $q = 1/e$ so that $K'/K = 1/\pi$ and hence there is no explicit known form for $k$ and thereby it is difficult to evaluate the sum in closed form.

Similarly if $s$ is an odd positive integer then the value of $$F(q) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{s}q^{n}}{1 - q^{n}}$$ is expressible in terms of $K, k, \pi$ where $q = \exp(-\pi K'/K)$. Evaluation of such sums in closed form is possible if $q = e^{-\pi\sqrt{r}}$ for some positive integer $r$ because in that case $k$ is algebraic and $K$ can be evaluated for at least some values of $r$. Also note that your sum uses $n = 0$ for which the denominator vanishes and it should be treated as $n \to 0$ instead of $n = 0$. Thus $n/(e^{n} - 1) \to 1$ as $n \to 0$.

The background material on elliptic and theta functions (including Ramanujan's functions) is covered in [my blog](https://paramanands.blogspot.in/p/archives.html) and it does require some patience to understand the theory completely. See some answers to similar questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1482985/72031) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1785144/72031).

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for your answer showing me where the field of maths lies that answers these sorts of questions. I will have a good look into this stuff. However, I won't mark it as the accepted answer, since my real question (what the mathematical reason is why these identities, especially $(1)$ and $(3)$, are so accurate) remains unanswered.

Comment: Also, thanks for pointing out that I shouldn't have $n=0$; that was a mistake on my part.

Comment: @Anon: I can understand your concern. And yes my answer does not deal with the approximations you have found. The basis of your approximation formula is Euler-Maclaurin summation formula.